# #region for JSX

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, jsx

I'm working with React/React Native with VS Code.

Some times, especially when you are trying to refactor someone's work, you need something like

```
#region regionName

...

#endregion
```

Is there any alternative for JSX?

Answer (score 17):

While it's a bit clunky, this is working for me, VS Code version `1.48.0`.

```
... JSX ...
{
  //#region
}
... JSX, will hide with the Fold All Regions command ...
{
  //#endregion
}
... JSX ...
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use

```
//#region something
...
your code
...
//#endregion
```

Comment: In JSX this is not working and inside {* #region name *) is not working

Comment: you have to put double back slash  `//` at the beginning

Comment: The question specifically asks about JSX, while this answer is not JSX compatible.

Comment: @PatFowler I think #region is not a part of JSX, its purely editor related, if you have ever used visual studio then you probably saw that before, basically #region is to make a block, show/hide some part of my code into a code file which make it more readable. Some time question is not enough to understand the issue, you have to read the detail a little bit. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm always open for any technical debate.

Comment: The question is specifically about how to enable region-based code folding in VS Code, which is how I found myself here. As far as I can tell, there is no way to use the VS concept of `#region` to enable code folding within a JSX code block.

Comment: This works for TSX

Answer (score 0):

The React framework offers a shorthand syntax for fragment components that appears as an empty tag: <></>.
You can use it like this.

```
<>
  <div>
    <p>Have A strong faith in god</p>
  </div>
</>
```

then the code editor will automatically show the down arrow to hide the code.

you can read the full documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax).

Peace be upon you.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to install region folding for vs and then in the workspace configuration under settings add this code

```
  "settings": {
        "maptz.regionfolder": {
            "[markdown]": {        
                "defaultFoldStartRegex": "\\<!--[\\s]*#region\\(collapsed\\)[\\s]*(.*)",
    
                "foldEnd": "<!-- #endregion -->",
                "foldEndRegex": "\\<!--[\\s]*#endregion",
                "foldStart": "<!-- #region [NAME] -->",
"settings": {
    "maptz.regionfolder": {
        "[markdown]": {        
            "defaultFoldStartRegex": "\\<!--[\\s]*#region\\(collapsed\\)[\\s]*(.*)",

            "foldEnd": "<!-- #endregion -->",
            "foldEndRegex": "\\<!--[\\s]*#endregion",
            "foldStart": "<!-- #region [NAME] -->",
            "foldStartRegex": "\\<!--[\\s]*#region[\\s]*(.*)"
        },
        "[javascript]": {
            "foldEnd": "/* #endregion */",
            "foldEndRegex": "(?<=\\/\\*|\\{\\/\\*)\\s*#endregion\\s*(.*)\\s*(?=\\*\\/|\\*\\/\\})",
            "foldStart": "/* #region [NAME] */",
            "foldStartRegex": "(?<=\\/\\*|\\{\\/\\*)\\s*#region\\s*(.*)\\s*(?=\\*\\/|\\*\\/\\})",
            "defaultFoldStartRegex": "^[\\s]*/\\*[\\s]*#region[\\s]*default\\s(.*)[\\s]*\\*/[\\s]*$",
            "foldDefinitions": [
              {
                "foldEndRegex": "\\*+/[\\s]*$",
                "foldStartRegex": "^[\\s]*/\\*\\*+" ,
                "isFoldedByDefault": true
              }
            ]
          }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: i specify the language as javascript and it works